# Unable to call all methods in one block in Play framework and Akka

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka

I am working on Play framework 2.5.3 and Akka 2.4.7 using Scala. I have an application made in play based webSockets using Akka. I am using the project as a jar in another project.

My code in new project looks like this:

For accepting connections:

```
val postActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[PostActorClass])

def wsSocket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue,JsValue]{ request =>

  ActorFlow.actorRef(out => wsConnObj.HandlerClass.props(out,postActor))


}
```

For getting references of all connections stored in my jar project:

```
def getConnReferences:Set[ActorRef] = {

 implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  val future = postActor ? GetReferences

  val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[Set[ActorRef]]

  (result)
}
```

For sending messages to all the references:

```
def sendMsg = {
  val msg = Json.parse("""{"username":"Server","message":"Reached finally.","pub_key":"empty","target":"user"}""")

  val refs = getConnReferences

  refs.foreach( _ ! msg)

}
```

I am trying to use these methods in my new project's `HomeController`. But unable to work them together, like `wsSocket` should be executed , then `sendMsg` (which itself calls `getConnReferences` also).
How will I achieve that? If am calling all these blocks in single action method, I can't establish connection even.

Code for `WebSocketConnect` class:

```
class WebSocketConnect @Inject() (cache:CacheApi) (implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem,materializer: Materializer){

  object HandlerClass {

    homelogger.info(logMessages.passingActorRef)

    def props(out: ActorRef, postActor: ActorRef) = {

        Props(new SocketHandlerClass(out, postActor, cache, postActorToUsernameMap))

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Awaiting a future and casting are generally bad ideas

Comment: I think the problem is your first code block. Specifically the line `wsConnObj.HandlerClass.props(out,postActor)`. What is `wsConObj` in this case? And what is `PostActorClass`? It would be helpful if you explain which code is part of your JAR and what is part of the consuming project.

Comment: wsConnObj is the reference to WebSocketConnect class and PostActorClass is the one where case 'GetReferences' is, it stores all connection references. Both class are part of my jar

Comment: I think you should show the code for `wsConnObj` too.